# Rails webpacker for some reason always think NODE_ENV is production despite I use `webpack-dev-server` and set NODE_ENV to development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, webpack

As title, I am using docker ruby 2.3.5 (ubuntu) environment, despite I have already setup NODE_ENV=development, when I try to intercept the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` I still see production, which I can't find anywhere it has been overridden. It only happens in the docker environment but not on my MacOS, not sure whats the reason?

Update: Here is Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml for reference:
https://gist.github.com/goodwill/b4e677ccf8fe0079183adeec35218812

Update: This is the error I end up with when running webpacker-dev-server:

```
04:08:37 webpacker.1 | /app/config/webpack/development.js:20
04:08:37 webpacker.1 |     https: settings.dev_server.https,
04:08:37 webpacker.1 |                               ^
04:08:37 webpacker.1 | 
04:08:37 webpacker.1 | TypeError: Cannot read property 'https' of undefined
04:08:37 webpacker.1 |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/webpack/development.js:20:31)
04:08:37 webpacker.1 |     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
04:08:37 webpacker.1 |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
04:08:37 webpacker.1 |     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
04:08:37 webpacker.1 |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
04:08:37 webpacker.1 |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
04:08:37 webpacker.1 |     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
04:08:37 webpacker.1 |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
04:08:37 webpacker.1 |     at requireConfig (/app/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:97:18)
04:08:37 webpacker.1 |     at /app/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:104:17
```

Comment: Are you sure you're properly setting the NODE_ENV inside docker?

Comment: Could you please post more details on how you're setting this up? Is there a  docker image or any `gist` you can provide in order to reproduce that?

Comment: See my docker file here: https://gist.github.com/goodwill/b4e677ccf8fe0079183adeec35218812

Comment: Please note my NODE_ENV=development is set in .env.development

Answer (score 2):

Docker containers will not collect environment variables from your local environment.

Set the environmental variable inside your Dockerfile. For example:

```
ENV NODE_ENV=development
```

Alternatively, you can run the container with that environmental variable from the command line:

```
$ docker run -e NODE_ENV=devlopment mycontainer
```

Comment: Yes this is already done that way but still when I try to `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` it shows `production`. Inside `bin/webpacker-dev-server` before the node package is invoked (`exec newenv, *cmdline`, line 41, it is still `development`. The strange part is that only happens inside container, when I run the project locally I don't have such issue.

Comment: As a very extreme measure, try setting this variable as a constant in your config/application.rb

Comment: I am pretty sure it wont help Justin- because I did step by step debug, the issue did not happen inside rails code, instead its something only happens when the node part is invoked, super strange. The part that's really sucks is that doesnt happen on my mac too :\

Comment: Try adding `NODE_ENV=development` to your docker-compose.yml and/or adding `RUN export NODE_ENV=development` do your Dockerfile. I'm not seeing either in your gist.

Comment: as I have already stated it is defined inside `.env.development` which is already specified in `docker-compose.yml` as the env source.